# chrome extension trap download dialog

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

so on a site that when you hit download, it always asks for a filename when I use a shortcut key to download something - ie it comes up with the "save as" dialog.   I want to build a chrome extension to trap that and provide my own filename.

I'm fine with building the extension, I've built lots, but I can't figure out how to trap/inject code into the "save as" dialog.  [and it generates a dynamic and complicated url that I can't predict, so I can't download from JS]

Is that possible to do?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is "it depends". [This page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/a) might offer a clue.

If it's an anchor, it looks like a `download` attribute with a value will be used as the suggested file name.

But then there is this:

> Note: if the Content-Disposition header has different information from the download attribute, resulting behavior may differ:
> If the header specifies a filename, it takes priority over a filename specified in the download attribute.

It might be possible to fiddle with that. Looks like [this guy did it on Firefox](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/rewrite-content-disposition/).

Comment: it's very much not an anchor - done by a bunch of obfuscated javascript and a very complicated coded url

Comment: Then rewriting the Content-Disposition might be the way to go. Try this extension: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/modheader/idgpnmonknjnojddfkpgkljpfnnfcklj?hl=en and see if it does the job for you.

Comment: I'm currently looking at chrome.webRequest.onBeforeRequest - it may do what I want